# How can I open form after closing it ? (with refresh)

Tags: c#, winforms, logic

I'm trying to make a close button and an open button, after form closing I want to open back the form with the new properties that i changed in my settings form. Can you help me? thank you in advance, have a nice day. Kaiiso

```
Browser browserForm = new Browser();

private void setBrowser(string activate)
{

        if (activate == "true")
        {
            browserForm.Show();
        }
        else if (activate == "false")
        {
            browserForm.Close();
        }
}
```

I know that is actually not working but it's a simple exemple :)

Comment: Well, firstly I would change your `activate` variable to a `bool` type. Then alter your `if` statement to: `if (activate) { /* do thing */ } else { /* do other thing */`

Comment: Also, what about your form are you wanting to change? Do you want to update `text boxes` with new data? Add all new elements? This question needs more detail in what you are needing to do

Comment: I want to change the screen to display the form, I choose the target screen from my own settings form

Comment: You are not changing the `screen`. Instead, you are changing the `form`'s property. You can use `.Show()` and `.Hide()` to display the form or to not display the form

Answer (score -1):

`Hide()` is your friend.

If you want only to hide it and after show in the same state as it was hidden. That's the way.

The other way it's to destroy the form and create a new form and show it.

Obviously you'll have to call some method that updates the UI with the new values, or bind properties, or something.

Comment: @Kaiiso "Obviously you'll have to call some method that updates the UI with the new values, or bind properties, or something."

Comment: Please add some code to help explain your answer and show your solution in action :)

Comment: @Symon I don't know what properties @Kaiiso changes. The question doesn't specify them and the code he proposes it's valid (use a string for bool... No). He just have to add a `ChangeProperties(Form frm)` method and call it before show.